# Find the equation of the orbit of following ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, differential-algebra

We call **orbit** associated to the initial datum $(t_0,x_0)$, the set of points:

$C=\{$**x**$(t;t_0,x_0), t \in T\}$.

Given the Matrix A:

\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

Write the equation of the orbit of the following ODE:

**x'(t)**$=A$**x(t)**

The solution of the system is :

$\begin{cases} x(t)=x_0cos(t)+y_0sin(t)\\y(t)=−x_0sin(t)+y_0cos(t)\end{cases}$

The equation of the orbit should be:
$x_2^2+y_2^2=x_0^2+y_0^2$, but how do I get a that from the solution of the system?

Comment: Solve for $s,c$ the linear system $\cases{x=x_0 c+y_0 s\\ y=-x_0 s + y_0 c}$ and after that, $s^2+c^2=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute $x(t)^2$ and $y(t)^2$ and observe that $\cos^2 (t)+ \sin^2 (t)=1.$ Then you should get

$$x(t)^2+y(t)^2=x_0^2+y_0^2.$$

Comment: I get, $x(t)^2+y(t)^2= 2(x_0^2+y_0^2)$

Comment: Something is wrong with your computations.

Comment: You are right. Thank you.